# Migrate ubuntu one to a new PC

Tags: ubuntu-one

I had my old PC with ubuntu one and had 1 folder (called projects) being sync. (over 2GB of data)

I got a new PC and transfered all my files to the new PC, including the "projects" folder.

Now ubuntu one shows that the "projects" folder can sync locally (but is not active).

I have a new device (my new PC) and other devices (old PC, not used any more)

My question is:

How can I sync my "projects" folder now? Just mark the option?

I am afraid that if I mark the option at ubuntu one, that I can loose data , or I have to download all the folder from the internet, or send all data to ubuntu one again.

Regards

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

You can just sign in to Ubuntu One, and if you already have all the files *in the exact same location* on as it was originally synchronized to the server from, on the new computer, you can choose to synchronize the folder in the Ubuntu One control panel after signing in, and you should be asked if you would like to merge the folder. Ubuntu One will re-scan the data, and if nothing is different from what is on the server, should sync up very quickly.

If there are changed or missing files though, then those will have to be re-synchronized, and may result in conflicts if what is local is different from what is on the server.

Keep a back-up, and verify everything is correct, after Ubuntu One has finished doing what it needs to do.